# ID set to 0 after submit

Tags: c#, razor

I know there are tons of examples that should solve my problem. I did all I could but still could not fix my problem. I have an HotelRoomID which is set to 0 after every submit. I use the HotelRoomID to retrieve data from the database.

This is my `BookingViewModel` (other properties are left out)

```
public int HotelRoomID { get; set; }
public HotelRoom HotelRoom { get; set; }
```

This is my `BookingController`. It may look weird but my form is a stepper form.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Stepper(BookingViewModel bookingViewModel) //problem starts here. HotelRoomID is 0...
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            switch (bookingViewModel.Step)
            {
                case 1:
                    GenerateForm(bookingViewModel);
                    _bookingViewModel.Step = 2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    var item = bookingViewModel.PersonList;
                    GenerateForm(bookingViewModel);
                    GenerateOverview(bookingViewModel);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    GenerateOverview(bookingViewModel);
                    break;
            }
            return View("Create",_bookingViewModel);
        }
        SaveBooking(_bookingViewModel);
        return View("home");
}
```

Below is the code of the razor form:

```
@model HoteldeBotel.Models.BookingViewModel

<div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Stepper", "Booking", Model))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @if (Model.PersonList != null)
                {
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-12 formContent">
                        <h3> Persoonsgegevens invullen </h3>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PersonList.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            <ul class="col-md-4 personFormList">
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonList[i].Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <li>
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.PersonList[i].Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.PersonList[i].Name, "", new { @class = "form-control numberOfPersons" })
                                </li>
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonList[i].Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <li>
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.PersonList[i].Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.PersonList[i].Email, "", new { @class = "form-control numberOfPersons" })
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressList[i].Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    <br />
                                    <label class="control-label">Straatnaam</label>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.AddressList[i].Name, "", new { @class = "form-control numberOfPersons" })
                                </li>
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressList[i].ZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <li>
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.AddressList[i].ZipCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.AddressList[i].ZipCode, "", new { @class = "form-control numberOfPersons" })
                                </li>
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressList[i].City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <li>
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.AddressList[i].City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.AddressList[i].City, "", new { @class = "form-control numberOfPersons" })
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        }
                        @if (Model.Step == 2)
                        {
                            Model.Step = 3;
                            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Next</button>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Next</button>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
            }
</div>
```

I hope someone can help me because I cannot fix this problem.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have checked in my side with your code and it works without any issue. I have changed `@using (Html.BeginForm("Stepper", "Booking", Model))` to `@using (Html.BeginForm("Stepper", "Booking", FormMethod.Post))`

Comment: Please check making this change and let me know the result.

Comment: I had tried that to. For some weird reason, it lefts out some other important properties. This gives me an error. The HotelRoomID property is important for retrieving data. By using FormMethod.Post, HotelRoomID remains 0. I have NO clue why this happens..

Comment: Can you give remote access with team viewer please?

Comment: Sure, how can i speak you privately?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188523/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-ffbbodie).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an hidden input field for `HotelRoomID` as follows:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HotelRoomID, new { Value = "yourValue"})
```

Moreover, change `@using (Html.BeginForm("Stepper", "Booking", Model))` to `@using (Html.BeginForm("Stepper", "Booking", FormMethod.Post))`